# Your own style for typing text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a typing code, using jQuery

How can i use, my own style?

Forexmaple i wanna wrtie a text like this :

```
Hi. My <span style="text-decoration: underline;">name</span> is <span style="color: #ff0000;">Amir</span>. <strong>Nice too see you</strong> guys!
```

But as you see, in "Data-Text" you can not, use css styles and html tags.

What shoud I do?

The Code:

```js
var $typer = $('.typer'),
    txt = $typer.data("text"),
    tot = txt.length,
    ch  = 0;

(function typeIt() {   
  if(ch > tot) return;
  $typer.text( txt.substring(0, ch++) );
  setTimeout(typeIt, ~~(Math.random()*(200-60+1)+60));
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="typer" data-text="Hi! My name is Al. I will guide you trough the Setup process."></span>
```

Comment: May it help you [link](https://jsfiddle.net/0z4Lyfbb/#&togetherjs=sH2pVbRTcD).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `data-text` to the `html` string, substitute `.html()` for `.text()` within `typeIt()` call

```js
var $typer = $('.typer'),
    txt = $typer.data("text"),
    tot = txt.length,
    ch  = 0;

(function typeIt() {   
  if(ch > tot) return;
  $typer.html( txt.substring(0, ch++) );
  setTimeout(typeIt, ~~(Math.random()*(200-60+1)+60));
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="typer" data-text='Hi. My <span style="text-decoration: underline;">name</span> is <span style="color: #ff0000;">Amir</span>. <strong>Nice too see you</strong> guys!
'></span>
```

Alternatively, you can create a `<template>` element, get `.content.childNodes` of `template` element; call `Array.prototype.slice.call()` with `template.content.childNodes` as parameter. Use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to iterate all nodes of `data-text` `html` string, utilize `.split()` with parameter `""` to create an array of each character of  current node `.textContent`.

Within `.reduce()` callback use `Promise.resolve()` as initial value, `Promise()` constructor to wait until `setTimeout` duration has expired before performing next task with current element of child nodes.

Check if node is `#text` node, if `true`, set `html` of `$typer` using `.html(function)`, else if `false` store `.textContent` of current node in a variable,  call `.empty()` on current node passed to `jQuery()`, `.append()` node to `$typer`, iterate `.textContent` of current node, call `.html()` on each character to set `.innerHTML` of appended node.

```js
var $typer = $('.typer')
    , txt = $("<template>", {
              html: $typer.data("text")
            })[0].content.childNodes;

Array.prototype.slice.call(txt).reduce(function(p, node) {
  return p.then(function() {
    var currentText = node.textContent.split("");
    if (node.nodeType !== 3) {
      var curr = node;
      $typer.append($(node).empty());
    }
    return currentText.reduce(function(promise, text) {
      return promise.then(function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(curr || $typer).html(function(_, html) {
              return html + text;
            });
            resolve()
          }, ~~(Math.random() * (200 - 60 + 1) + 60))
        })
      })
    }, Promise.resolve())
  })
}, Promise.resolve());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<span class="typer" data-text='Hi. My <span style="text-decoration: underline;">name</span> is <span style="color: #ff0000;">Amir</span>. <strong>Nice too see you</strong> guys!
'></span>
```

Comment: This works nice but you see the system type out the carrot tags before rendering the span.

Comment: @guest271314 thanks for your answer.

But in the internet explorer, it doesn't work. Synax eror. Why?

Comment: @AmirEbrahimi Have not used ie in some time. Could be spread element and `Array.from()`. See updated post.